# Substituting values in a numpy masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to substitute  some values in a `numpy` `masked array`, but my mask is being dropped:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5], mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
a[a < 2] = 999
```

The result is:

```
masked_array(data = [999 2 3 999 5],
mask = [False False False False False],
fill_value = 999999)
```

But what I want is:

```
masked_array(data = [999 2 3 -- 5],
mask = [False False False  True False],
fill_value = 999999)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Python 2.7 and numpy 1.7.1 on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: This is a long-standing gotcha/design-bug/feature with masked arrays.  Basically, beware of assigning using boolean arrays when using masked arrays.  A completely different (much cleaner) missing value system was added to numpy a few years back, but has been pulled back out until numpy 2.0 for various reasons.

Comment: @JoeKington, *sigh*. I suspected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not doing the substitution correctly, try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5], mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> a.data[a < 2] = 999
>>> a
 masked_array(data = [999 2 3 -- 5],
         mask = [False False False  True False],
   fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: I have tested it on numpy `1.7.1`