# Python: how to replace values in masked array according to a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array. I want to replace the values `> 5` with `1`, and the values `<= 5` with `0`.
I also must to take into account the invalid values (`999`).

1) My array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([   [[2, 5, 999],[0, 12, 1]], [[999, 8, 7],[7, 11, 6]]   ])
>>> a
array([[[  2,   5, 999],
        [  0,  12,   1]],

       [[999,   8,   7],
        [  7,  11,   6]]])
```

2) I mask the invalid values:

```
>>> mask_a = (a==999)
>>> a_masked = numpy.ma.masked_array(a, mask = mask_a)
>>> print a_masked
[[[2 5 --]
  [0 12 1]]

 [[-- 8 7]
  [7 11 6]]]
```

3) I replace the values <= 5 with zeros:

```
>>> a_masked[a_masked<=5]=0
>>> print a_masked
[[[0 0 --]
  [0 12 0]]

 [[-- 8 7]
  [7 11 6]]]
```

4) I want to replace now the values > 5 with ones:

```
>>> a_masked[a_masked>5]=1
>>> print a_masked
[[[0 0 1]
  [0 1 0]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

Why doesn't it take into account the values=999 which were already masked???

I want to get the following result:

```
    [[[0 0 --]
      [0 1 0]]

     [[-- 1 1]
      [1 1 1]]]
```

Comment: I asked exactly [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957192/substituting-values-in-a-numpy-masked-array) yesterday...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply:

```
>>> a[a != 999] = (a[a != 999] > 5)
>>> a
array([[[  0,   0, 999],
        [  0,   1,   0]],

       [[999,   1,   1],
        [  1,   1,   1]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.piecewise(a, [a < 5, numpy.logical_and(a > 5,a <999) ,a >= 999], [0, 1,999])
```

I think would do what you want with one line ...

Comment: Even though this is a longer line than the one in my answer, (+1) for pointing out `np.piecewise`. :-) I did not know it existed.

Comment: Thank you, @Joran. But it seems a bit complicated for me :-)